# Django ChoiceArrayField: how to set a default value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

In the context of Django2.0 and the admin part,
if the database backend is PostgreSQL;

Is it possible to specify "NULL" as the column of a field by default ?

For example,

```
class ChoiceArrayField(ArrayField):

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': forms.MultipleChoiceField,
            'choices': self.base_field.choices,
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(ArrayField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

And the model field is:

```
capabilities = ChoiceArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=PEER_CAPS, blank=True, null=True), default=list)
```

where

```
PEER_CAPS = (
    ("",                "None"),
    ("blackholing",     "blackholing"),
    ("irrguard",        "irrguard"),
)
```

Right now, the default is "None", but it saves the value `""` because it needs an iterable, so I cannot have a variable with value equal to None. This is just fine for the admin web app.

BUT before I save it to the database I would like to set capabilities to be NULL or an empty list (since the corresponding table in PostgreSQL is an `array`)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

this is fixed by declaring twice the field as follows:

```
capabilities = ChoiceArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=PEER_CAPS, blank=True, null=True), default=list, blank=True, null=True)
```